# What kind of bug is this? Small, slower than an ant, black head, red body

Tags: species-identification, entomology

It is very small but it is slower than an ant. It has a black head and six legs with a red body. I’m in North Carolina.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Please [edit] your post to include as much of the following information as possible to improve your chances of getting a good answer: 0) size estimate; 1) photos from multiple angles if possible; 2) the location (e.g. country and region — the more specific the better) where you observed this organism; 3) habitat information — e.g.s: (the building is) in a forest (conifers vs. deciduous), next to water (lake vs. river vs. ocean), etc.; and 4) any other behavior you observed. [See detailed tag info page](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/species-identification/info).

Comment: It actually looks like a bug to me - a true bug (Hemiptera) nymph.  Unfortunately, it doesn't resemble anything I am familiar with, but luckily there are lots of bug specialists around - someone should be able to point you in the right direction!